# How to add custom values to Wordpress search

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have created a fronted editor (using ckeditor) for wordpress. For now it edits fields in template (like part of section where is title and description) and saves it to custom table

It's my table

---

id | template | selector | date | content | lang

---

**template** - template name example: expertise.php

**selector** - unique jquery selector for template example: .sec.sec3 > .content
(its for selecting editable content, content that i dont want the user to be able to edit will be outside of this selection example .sec.sec3 > .button )

**date**- for revisions

**content** - saved page html

**lang** - wpml lang code

Function for getting latest fields ( for latest date and current lang)

```
function mwe_get_template_fields($template){
global $wpdb;
$t = $wpdb->prefix.'mwe_template_fields';

if(ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE !== NULL){

    $sql = $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * FROM $t
    WHERE template = %s
    AND date IN (SELECT max(date) FROM $t)
    AND lang = %s
    GROUP BY selector
    ORDER BY date DESC
    ", $template,ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE);

    $result = $wpdb->get_results( $sql, ARRAY_A );

    if(empty($result)){
        global $sitepress;
        $lang=$sitepress->get_default_language();

        $sql = $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * FROM $t
        WHERE template = %s
        AND date IN (SELECT max(date) FROM $t)
        AND lang = %s
        GROUP BY selector
        ORDER BY date DESC
        ", $template,$lang);

        $result = $wpdb->get_results( $sql, ARRAY_A );
    }
 }else{
    $sql = $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * FROM $t
    WHERE template = %s
    AND date IN (SELECT max(date) FROM $t)
    GROUP BY selector
    ORDER BY date DESC
    ", $template);
    $result = $wpdb->get_results( $sql, ARRAY_A );
 }

 $return=array();
 foreach($result as $field){
    $return[$field['selector']]= str_replace('\"','"',$field['content']);
 }

 return $return;
}
```

My search.php (very simple)

```
<?php
get_header(); ?>
<section class="sec-pagetop">
    <article class="pagetop gradient2">
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Search</h1>
        </div>
    </article>
    <span class="go-to" data-target=".search-list"></span>
</section>
<section class="sec search-list">
    <div class="container">
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
        <?php
        // Start the loop.
        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" ca;ss="fadeInAnim">
            <header class="entry-header">
                <?php the_title( sprintf( '<h2 class="entry-title"><a href="%s" rel="bookmark">', esc_url( get_permalink() ) ), '</a></h2>' ); ?>
            </header><!-- .entry-header -->
            <div class="entry-summary">
                <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
            </div><!-- .entry-summary -->
            <a class="btn-more" href="<?=get_permalink()?>"><?_e('See more')?></a>
        </article><!-- #post-## -->
        <?
        endwhile;

        the_posts_pagination( array(
            'prev_text'          => __( 'Previous page' ),
            'next_text'          => __( 'Next page' ),
            'before_page_number' => '<span class="meta-nav screen-reader-text">' . __( 'Page' ) . ' </span>',
        ) );
    endif;
    ?>
    </div>
</section>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I can easly search in content of this fields, even get url based on what posts uses this template, but how can i add them to search?

Also i have idea, maybe instead of chaning search, i can provide my own posts for `while ( have_posts() )`? Overwrite global posts for search archive page.

**Note: I dont want to save my fields to wp_posts.**

**Note2: I dont want to use custom search form and function, i want to add my results to wordpress search so it will be compatibile with all themes**

Comment: You can intervene in the construction of the SQL for WordPress's standard search operation by providing a `posts_search` filter. Read this. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/posts_search/  Using various hooks is the best way for plugins to extend WordPress functionality. Here's the API lookup. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/

Comment: @O.Jones This way i wont be able to `SELECT` custom table